# how to solve multichoices

Tags: javascript

```js
var questions = [
["Which one is not an object oriented programming ?" , "c++", "c","cobal","B","C", "c",'cobal'],
["whic one is used for styling pages ?" , "JQuery","javascript", "css", "A","C","css",'jquery'],

];

question = questions[pos][0];
 A = questions[pos][1];
 B = questions[pos][2];
 C = questions[pos][3];
  
test.innerHTML ="<h1>" + question +"<h1>";
test.innerHTML +="<input type='checkbox' name='choices' value='A'>" + A +"<br>";
 test.innerHTML +="<input type='checkbox' name='choices' value='B'>" + B +"<br>";
 test.innerHTML +="<input type='checkbox' name='choices' value='C'>" + C +"<br>";
 test.innerHTML +="<button onclick='check()'>Submit Test</button>";

for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
 if(choices[i].checked){
  //checkboxChecked.push(choices[i].value);
  choice = choices[i].value;

  if(choices[i].value == questions[pos][5] ){
    correctAnswer++;

  }else{
   rAnswer +=questions[pos][0] +"   :" + questions[pos][6] +"   " + questions[pos][7]+ "<br>";
  }

 }
```

actually i want to compare mutlti choices and get correct result from them and display them, the question array consist of question itself, plus right answer , like 4 and 5th element of question array are correct answer, which i compare down with choices and get the correct answer, can some one help me to solve this problems 
thanks in advance

Comment: I assumed the two checkbox are the right answer, right?

Comment: yes two element in array 4 and 5 are right answer , and i wana compare with down checkboxes to get two correct answer and display them

Comment: Thanks Jose , but code is not working even though i made changes according to , can you check it what is wrong with it?

Comment: the answer that I posted is working, just click the "Run code snippet" . Do you mean to your code? or what something else?

Comment: Thanks Jose its working for me two , i really appreciate your help

Comment: If it's working and my answer helps you, could you accept my answer?

Comment: yes i accepted it , what do you mean?

Comment: If you scroll to my answer, you can see below of the votes number a check symbol, if you click there, you will accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can display  and compare the checked answers, the example is only for 1 position but you can put it inside a loop and apply as many questions as you have in the array:

```js
var questions = [
["Which one is not an object oriented programming ?" , "c++", "c","cobal","B","C", "c",'cobal'],
["whic one is used for styling pages ?" , "JQuery","javascript", "css", "A","C","css",'jquery']
];

var test = document.getElementById("questions"),
    pos = 1;

question = questions[pos][0];
 A = questions[pos][1];
 B = questions[pos][2];
 C = questions[pos][3];
  
test.innerHTML ="<h1>" + question +"<h1>";
test.innerHTML +="<input type='checkbox' name='choices1' value='A'>" + A +"<br>";
 test.innerHTML +="<input type='checkbox' name='choices1' value='B'>" + B +"<br>";
 test.innerHTML +="<input type='checkbox' name='choices1' value='C'>" + C +"<br>";
 test.innerHTML +="<button onclick='check()'>Submit Test</button>";
  
 function check(){
     var choices = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[name=choices1]:checked"));
     
     if(choices.length >= 2){
        if((choices[0].value == questions[pos][4] || choices[0].value == questions[pos][5]) && (choices[1].value == questions[pos][4] || choices[1].value == questions[pos][5]) ){
          console.log('RIGHT ANSWER');
        }else{
          var rAnswer = questions[pos][0] +"   :" + questions[pos][6] +"   " + questions[pos][7]+ "<br>";
          console.log(rAnswer);
        }
     }
 }
```

```html
<div id="questions">

</div>
```